# Rbomongo and Robo3t on launch error dialog

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, robo3t

I am trying to access database with in robomongo 0.9.0 version it showing error.Failed to create SSH tunnel.Delete previous robomongo setup and installed robo 3t with in usr/local/bin folder using Ubuntu command getting same error.

[image]

Comment: You can check this thread on github https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1452

Comment: I have deleted previous robomongo setup and install new robo3t and getting same error for robo3t also.

Comment: Check the solutions given in the above link

Comment: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1453 this link also has a temporary workaround